# Python Scatterplot: Changing color based on both X and Y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot, colormap

I've tried to recreate the image attached using cmaps as well as with if/else statements.

[image: Example]

My current attempt is based upon the advice given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803570/python-matplotlib-scatter-plot-specify-color-points-depending-on-conditions/40804861)

I tried using 1.8<=x<=2.2 but I get an error.

Here is my current code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 500
# center, variation, number of points
x = np.random.normal(2,0.2,N)
y = np.random.normal(2,0.2,N)
colors = np.where(x<=2.2,'r',np.where(y<=2.2,'b','b'))
plt.scatter(x , y, c=colors)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To make that plot, you need to pass an array with the color of each point. In this case the color is the distance to the point (2, 2), since the distributions are centered on that point.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 500
# center, variation, number of points
x = np.random.normal(2,0.2,N)
y = np.random.normal(2,0.2,N)

# we calculate the distance to (2, 2).
# This we are going to use to give it the color.
color = np.sqrt((x-2)**2 + (y-2)**2)

plt.scatter(x , y, c=color, cmap='plasma', alpha=0.7)
# we set a alpha
# it is what gives the transparency to the points.
# if they suppose themselves, the colors are added.

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks so much Lucas. I think its close enough when I use the reverse colormap.