# How set progressive colors on scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to represent points in 2d space with according label, I also want the points to have the same color as their label and finally I need the colors of the labels to be progressive.

I looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution.
This is my current implementation :

```py
for i in range(0, encoder.classes_.size):
       plt.scatter(data_pca_reduced[i][0], data_pca_reduced[i][1],
                   label=i, cmap=plt.get_cmap('viridis'))
```

And this is the result :

[image: Scatter plot result]

As you can see the labels colors are not progressive.

Comment: Hey, have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803570/python-matplotlib-scatter-plot-specify-color-points-depending-on-conditions

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236566/setting-different-color-for-each-series-in-scatter-plot-on-matplotlib

Comment: You need one single scatter only. No loop. And you need a [mcve] in the question, such that people feel motivated to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks the second link is exactly what I was looking for !

Now this is the working code :

```
colors = matplotlib.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, encoder.classes_.size))
for i, c in zip(range(encoder.classes_.size), colors):
       plt.scatter(data_pca_reduced[i][0], data_pca_reduced[i][1], label=i, color=c)
```

And this is the result :
[image: result image]

Comment: Can you add a plot with the correct colors ? It would be delicious to the eye ;)