# conditional line color results in ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, valueerror

I am trying to plot a linegraph with matplotlib.pytplot and have a dataframe df with the shape `(42,7)`. The dataframe has the following structur (only showing relevant columns):

```
timepoint   value   point
2021-01-01   10      0
2021-02-01   20      0
....
2021-11-01   10      0
2021-12-01   50      1
2022-01-01   60      1
...
```

I try to plot conditional color in the following way (that each value with point=0 is blue and each value with point=1 is red):

```
import numpy as np
col = np.where(df['point'] == 0, 'b', 'r')


plt.plot(df['timepoint'], df['value'], c=col)
plt.show()
```

and I get the error massage:

> ValueError: array(['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',
> 'b', 'b', 'b',
> 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r',
> 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r',
> 'r', 'r', 'r'], dtype='<U1') is not a valid value for color

When I look at this question [ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: What is causing this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531429/valueerror-invalid-rgba-argument-what-is-causing-this-error) , I don't find any solution as the shape of my color array is: `col.shape` is `(42, )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here to define the colors of your line graph (as they did [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40804861/16120011) with a scatter one) because in the former, the `c` parameter expects a single color for the whole line while in the latter, you can provide an array of colors that will be mapped to the points.

So, here is one possible option to address that :

```
(_, p0), (_, others) = df.groupby(df["point"].eq(0), sort=False)

plt.plot(p0.timepoint, p0.value, c="b", label="0 Points")
plt.plot(others.timepoint, others.value, c="r", label="Others")

plt.legend()
plt.show();
```

Or with [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) / [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) :

```
other_points = df["point"].loc[lambda s: s.ne(0)].unique()

(
    df.pivot(index="timepoint", columns="point", values="value")
        .plot(style={0: "b", **{k: "r" for k in other_points}})
)
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error you're encountering is because the c parameter in the plt.plot() function expects a valid color specification for each data point, but you're providing an array of color names ('b' for blue and 'r' for red) which isn't a valid value for the c parameter.

To plot conditional colors for your line graph, you can use a loop to iterate through the DataFrame rows and plot each segment with the desired color. Here's how you can do it (with sample dataframe):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'timepoint': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01'],
    'value': [10, 20, 10, 50, 60],
    'point': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'timepoint' column to datetime type
df['timepoint'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timepoint'])

# Initialize variables to keep track of the previous point value and color
prev_point = None
prev_color = None

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # Check the 'point' value for the current row
    current_point = row['point']

    # Set the color based on the 'point' value
    if current_point == 0:
        color = 'b'  # Blue for point=0
    else:
        color = 'r'  # Red for point=1

    # If the point value has changed, create a new segment in the plot
    if prev_point is not None and current_point != prev_point:
        ax.plot(df.loc[df.index[index - 1]:index - 1, 'timepoint'], df.loc[df.index[index - 1]:index - 1, 'value'], c=prev_color, label=f'Point {prev_point}', marker='o')  # Add marker='o' to display points

    ax.plot([row['timepoint']], [row['value']], c=color, marker='o')  # Add marker='o' to display points

    # Update previous point and color
    prev_point = current_point
    prev_color = color

# Add labels, legend, and show the plot
ax.set_xlabel('Timepoint')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
ax.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.show()
```

We can use `np.where` approach too. We can use `plt.scatter` to achieve that, like code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'timepoint': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01'],
    'value': [10, 20, 10, 50, 60],
    'point': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'timepoint' column to datetime type
df['timepoint'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timepoint'])

# Use np.where to conditionally set colors
col = np.where(df['point'] == 0, 'b', 'r')

# Create the scatter plot with conditional colors
plt.scatter(df['timepoint'], df['value'], c=col, s=50)

# Show the plot
plt.xlabel('Timepoint')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('Conditional Scatter Plot')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

This is updated code to create linegraph, but using loop to differentiate between color:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'timepoint': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-01', '2021-11-01', '2021-12-01', '2022-01-01'],
    'value': [10, 20, 10, 50, 60],
    'point': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'timepoint' column to datetime type
df['timepoint'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timepoint'])

# Use np.where to conditionally set colors
col = np.where(df['point'] == 0, 'b', 'r')

# Create the line graph with conditional colors
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for color, group in df.groupby(col):
    ax.plot(group['timepoint'], group['value'], label=color)

# Add labels, legend, and show the plot
ax.set_xlabel('Timepoint')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
You can check on my kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebooka2f9d7419b)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803570/specify-color-points-depending-on-conditions why does it work with `np.where` in that case without any (slow) loops?

Comment: We can. I have updated my answer and kaggle code with `np.where` approach