# How to color some point by a range of values pyplot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to learn python and to make graphs. I'm stucked in this problem, I want to color a certain part of the scatter plot by the range of the values.
Here I annotated `SGA`, `Wemby` and `Giannis` manually (with `plt.annotate` and searching for the specific row in the `dataframe`). Is it possible to annotate and color points by a value range (example color all the point with 1.5 < block < 3) without manually search for the single player row?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.scatter(x=df["BLK"], y=df["STL"], s=32, alpha=.8, vmin=None, vmax=None)
plt.scatter(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Victor Wembanyama'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Victor Wembanyama'], c="b")
plt.scatter(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Shai Gilgeous-Alexander'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Shai Gilgeous-Alexander'], c="y")
plt.scatter(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'], c="g")
plt.annotate("Wemby",(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Victor Wembanyama'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Victor Wembanyama']))
plt.annotate("SGA",(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Shai Gilgeous-Alexander'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Shai Gilgeous-Alexander']))
plt.annotate("Giannis",(df["BLK"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo'], df["STL"][df["PLAYER"] == 'Giannis Antetokounmpo']))
plt.xlabel("Blocks")
plt.ylabel("Steals")
sns.despine()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Tried:
`plt.annotate(df["PLAYER"][df["STL"] == 1.6],(df["BLK"][df["STL"] == 1.6]], df["STL"][df["STL"] == 1.6]]))`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and clearer to just call `sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='BLK', y='STL', hue='PLAYER', legend='full')`?

Comment: idk, I read a lot of sites who suggested to learn pyplot over plotly and seaburn, I'd give it a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40804861/7750891

Comment: @SONZO But (1) you already imported seaborn, so why not use it? (2) Seaborn makes this task extremely simple--as JohanC shows, it is a single function call to replace around 8 lines of code.